# Android Open GL ES strange issue

Tags: java, android, opengl-es

i m building a game for android and i noticed on tracer a strange issue after trying to optimize my calls to open gl. 
The game runs perfect , and at most of the time bellow 16 fps , but in some frames exceeds 20 21 millis per frame , so i noticed this on allmost every glUniform1f , glUniform3fv , glUniform1i calls :

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: No such property: PROGRAM_STATE/PROGRAMS/${program}/ACTIVE_UNIFORMS/14/UNIFORM_VALUE
Error applying transformations for glUniform3fv(location = 3, count = 1, v = [0.0, 100.0, 0.0])
```

on frames > 16 millis this calls take  more time to execute.

Here is a sample of draw calls:

```
 GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, this.MyGLTexture);
    GLES20.glUseProgram(this.Params.Programm);
    GLES20.glUniform1i(this.Params.uTextureLoc, 0);
    GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(this.Params.uMMatrixHandle, 1, false,this.MMatrixClip, 0);
    Matrix.multiplyMM(this.MMatrix, 0, GamePlayRenderer.MVPMatrix, 0,this.MMatrix, 0);
    GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(this.Params.uMVPMatrixHandle, 1, false,this.MMatrix, 0);
    GLES20.glUniform1f(this.Params.uAlphaFactor,this.alphaFactor);
    GLES20.glUniform1f(this.Params.Fader,fader);
    GLES20.glUniform3fv(this.Params.uEyePos,1,cameraPos,0);
    GLES20.glUniform3fv(this.Params.uLightPos,1,lightPos,0);
    GLES20.glUniform3fv(this.Params.uMatAmbient,this.MatAmbient.length/3,this.MatAmbient,0);
    GLES20.glUniform3fv(this.Params.uMatDifusse,this.MatDifusse.length/3,this.MatDifusse,0);
    GLES20.glUniform3fv(this.Params.uMatSpecular,this.MatSpecular.length/3,this.MatSpecular,0);
    GLES20.glUniform3fv(this.Params.uMatAlpha,this.MatAlpha.length/3,this.MatAlpha,0);

    GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(this.Params.aPosHandle);
    GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(this.Params.aTextHandle);
    GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(this.Params.aNorHandle);
    GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(this.Params.aMatIdHandle);

    GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(this.Params.aPosHandle, 3, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, 40, 0);
    GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(this.Params.aTextHandle, 2, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, 40, 12);
    GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(this.Params.aNorHandle, 3, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, 40, 20);
    GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(this.Params.aMatIdHandle, 2, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, 40, 32);


    GLES20.glDrawArrays(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLES,this.ObjectStart,this.ObjectCount);
```